# submit button does not clear cookie in express

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I am setting up a very simple web app. In my pug file I have the following code:

```
extends layout.pug

block content
section#content
  h2 Welcome, #{name}!
  form(action='/goodbye', method='post')
  button(type='submit') Goodbye!
footer
  p An app to help you study
```

and in my app.js file for that particular route, this is the code I have:

```
app.post('/goodbye', (req, res) => {
res.clearCookie('username');
res.redirect('/hello');
});
```

When I press the submit button nothing happens.  Not sure why this is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is outside your form. You have to tab it one more to make it in.

**Wrong**

```
 form(action='/goodbye', method='post')
 button(type='submit') Goodbye!
```

**Good**

```
  form(action='/goodbye', method='post')
      button(type='submit') Goodbye!
```

And if you wan't to use your button outside your form you have to specify it like so :

```
button(type="submit" form="yourFormId")
```

Comment: Good. Have fun ! Don't miss to place this response as solved